# Template argument deduction for constrained parameter (bitset size) fails

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to make the compiler deduce the parameter `size_t L` using a constrained by concepts template argument?

That's the best I got

```
template <typename T, size_t L>
concept def_bitset = std::is_same<T, std::bitset<L>>::value;

template<size_t L>
void stamp(def_bitset<L> auto const &b) {
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

This works if I call it passing the `L` as a template argument

```
stamp<4>(bitset<4>{0b0110});
```

I'd like to be able to call stamp without repeating the bitset size.

Comment: Does this compile if you pass a larger L (for example) to `stamp`?

Comment: It doesn't, that's a note from the compiler `note: the expression 'std::is_same<T, std::bitset<L> >::value [with T = std::bitset<4>; L = 5]' evaluated to 'false'`

Comment: Now, I apologize in advance if this is just me misunderstanding an overly simplified example, but I don't see why you'd need any C++20 machinery here.  `stamp` can simply be defined to take `void stamp(std::bitset<L> const &b)` - Tried and tested, simple and readable.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Doesn't it seem odd though that this won't work as well? I imagine more complex concepts are the end goal here.

Comment: While it looks reasonable at first glance, this happens during function template overload resolution so it requires *two* concurrent template deductions. I'm not sure the language is equipped to deal with that.

Comment: thank you @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, this is part of a concepts study, but thank you for the fix, it indeed works!

Comment: @kabanus - Not really that odd, no. I may be biased, but it was always my understanding concepts are meant to empower regular use of templates (as opposed to relying on SFINAE hackery), not replace said regular use.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's reasonablee, it just seemed at first glance the deduction would work. I think Quentin though maybe right, so my first glance would be wrong.

Comment: @Quentin I replaced the concept with a regular template class that inherits `bitset` (and that's all), and changed the `stamp` definition to take this wrapper. In this case auto deduction works - should there be a difference?

Comment: @kabanus yes, that's still covered by the (admittedly convoluted) rules of function template overloading, specifically the derived-to-base implicit conversions. But the more I think about it, the less I'm sure that the deductions for the argument type and the concept need to occur at the same time rather than in sequence -- it does not surprise me that this is not supported, but I'm not sure how hard it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concepts exist to check constraints on template arguments. A concept is not a type, despite appearing in the same location as a type can when employing terse notation. It doesn't carry any type information that can be used for template argument deduction.

To illustrate it, let's rewrite your terse function template definition to its explicit form

```
template<size_t L, def_bitset<L> T>
void stamp(T const &b) {
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

This equivalent form should illustrate the problem. The concept can only check the constraint holds *after* `T` and `L` have been deduced. But while `T` is easy enough to deduce, this function template definition is not written in a way that allows deducing `L` from `b`. Therefore you encountered the need to specify `L` explicitly. The concept is of no help, because it's not part of the function argument, it's part of the template itself.

Now, it just so happens that the use case in the question doesn't really require a concept at all.

```
template<size_t L>
void stamp(std::bitset<L> const &b) {
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

This is a function template that expects specializations of `std::bitset`.